# Extract the data specified in brackets '[ ]' from a string message in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to extract fields from below Log message.

Example:

> Ignoring entry, Affected columns [column1:column2], reason[some reason], Details[some entry details]

I need to extract the data specified in the brackets `[ ]` for  "Affected columns,reason, Details"

What would be the efficient way to extract these fields in Python?

*Note: I can modify the log message format if needed.*

Comment: `re.findall('\[([^]]+), str)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are free to change the log format, it's easiest to use a common data format - I'd recommend JSON for such data. It is structured, but lightweight enough to write it even from custom bash scripts. The [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html) allows you to directly convert it to native python objects:

```
import json  # python has a default parser
# assume this is your log message
log_line = '{"Ignoring entry" : {"Affected columns": [1, 3], "reason" : "some reason", "Details": {}}}'
data = json.loads(log_line)
print("Columns to ignore:", data["Ignoring entry"]["Affected columns"])
```

---

If you want to work with the current format, you'll have to work with `str` methods or the `re` module.

For example, you could do this:

```
log_msg = "Ignoring entry, Affected columns [column1:column2], reason[some reason], Details[some entry details]"
def parse_log_line(log_line):
  if log_line.startswith("Ignoring entry"):
    log_data = {
    for element in log_line.split(',')[1:]:  # parse all elements but the header
      key, value = element.partition('[')
      if value[-1] != ']':
        raise ValueError('Malformed Content. Expected %r to end with "]"' % element)
      value = value[:-1]
      log_data[key] = value
    return log_data
  raise ValueError('Unrecognized log line type')
```

Many parsing tasks are <strike>best</strike> compactly handled by the [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#module-re). It allows you to use regular expressions. They are very powerful, but difficult to maintain if you are not used to it. In your case, the following would work:

```
log_data = {key: value for key, value in re.findall(',\s?(.+?)\s?\[(.+?)\]', log_line)}
```

The re works like this:

- `,` a literal comma, separating your entries
- `\s*` an arbitrary sequence of whitespace after the comma, before the next element
- `(.+?)` any non-whitespace characters (the key, captured via `'()'`)
- `\s*` an arbitrary sequence of whitespace between key and value
- `\[` a literal `[`
- `(.+?)` the *shortest* sequence of non-whitespace characters before the next element (the value, captured via `'()'`)
- `\]` a literal `]`

The symbols `*`, `+` and `?` mean "any", "more than one", and "as few as possible".

Comment: Why not simply `re.findall('\[([^]]+), str)`?

Comment: @MarounMaroun Primarily because `str` methods are more suitable to get across that writing your own parser is a bad idea. ;) Secondly, your re doesn't give the keys, and is missing the closing quotes. The re `',(.+?) ?\[(.+?)\]'` works better, but also doesn't help readability.

Comment: @sreekanthramagiri Glad to help. Please accept the answer if it solves the problem.