# Python3 - Extracting data from a user inputted string. Could be in the wrong format

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x, split

I've been trying to find a way of taking a user input which should be in the form:
[x<sub>1</sub>,y<sub>1</sub>][x<sub>2</sub>,y<sub>2</sub>]
This whereby x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>2</sub> are integer values.

The point is in making a chess piece move from position *a* to position *b*

My aim is to have the user input it as so:

```
move = input("\nSyntax: '[x,y][x,y]'")
```

My intent is to break apart the string so that I end up with two lists.

From = [x<sub>1</sub>,y<sub>1</sub>]

To = [x<sub>2</sub>,y<sub>2</sub>]

The nearest thing I found was: *[Extract the data specified in brackets '[ ]' from a string message in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39138999/extract-the-data-specified-in-brackets-from-a-string-message-in-python)*.

However, for such a simple string in my case, I'm sure there's an easier way - what's most efficient. Also, in this case, the user may make a typo etc... How would I make sure it's in the format [x<sub>1</sub>,y<sub>1</sub>][x<sub>2</sub>,y<sub>2</sub>]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your input string is like:

```
my_str =  '[x1,y1][x2,y2]'
```

For storing the values in separate variables, you may `strip` the `[` and `]` from the corners and replace `][` with `,`. Then split the string on `,` as:

```
x1, y1, x2, y2 = my_str.strip('[]').replace('][', ',').split(',')
```

The values hold by `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2` will be:

```
>>> x1, y1, x2, y2
('x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2')
```

Then for storing the values to list, you may do:

```
from_list = [x1, y2]
to_list = [x2, y2]
```

---

If you are ok with changing the format of input string from `[x1,y1][x2,y2]` to `[x1,y1],[x2,y2]` (comma between `][`), then you may use `ast.literal_eval` as:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> my_str =  '[1,2],[3,4]'

>>> from_list, to_list = literal_eval(my_str)
```

Comment: Would there be a simple way of knowing whether the string was not in the format [x1,y1][x2,y2]? Thus throwing an error to the user.

Comment: Put the code you are using to transform the string within `try`/`except`. within the `except` block throw him the error message

Answer (score 1):

```
ove = "\nSyntax: '[12,22][32,4215]'"

a1 = ove.find('[') + 1
a2 = ove.find(']')
a3 = ove.rfind('[') + 1
a4 = ove.rfind(']')

print(a3)
print(a4)
From = [int(s) for s in ove[a1:a2].split(',')]
To = [int(s) for s in ove[a3:a4].split(',')]

print(From, To)
```

Tested Fine.